# jQuery Hover Issue With Children

Tags: jquery, jquery-hover

So here is my code:

```
$('div.gallery-nav-next').hover(
    function () {
        $intervalRightScroll = setInterval(function () {
            if (!$inAnim)
                instance._slideHover('right', 5, $sliderOptions['scrollSpeed']);
         }, $sliderOptions['scrollSpeed']);
    },
    // Callback
    function () {
        clearInterval($intervalRightScroll);
        $inAnim = false;
    }
);
```

Which works fine, as long as the user doesnt hover over any child elements. I have one child element containing an image of an arrow, which is where the issue is. The hover works fine as long as the user is not hovering over the image, but when the user hovers over the arrow, the slider stops.

How would I go about making the hover event continue until the user stop hovering over the parent, rather than the child?

Comment: A demo would be quite useful

Comment: Have you tried applying the hover event to the child as well? As in `$('div.gallery-nav-next, .childElement').hover(...`

Comment: Got it working, I just added the child to the selector, and only used setInterval if $intervalRightScroll was == null.